# how do i avoid showing layout in internet explorer mobile

Tags: windows-phone-7

I honesty don't know how to put this. In mango version of windows phone internet explorer shows a black semi transparent layer when a link is tapped how can I avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do clearly understand what you are telling, but unfortunately, you can't avoid that. It is simply an indication that the link has been clicked. For usability sake.

This is for existing web-pages/sites. But if you are trying to develop an web-app using PhoneGap or something else, then you can change these links as JavaScript/jQuery events instead, and that should probably avoid it.